# How to have a circle shape like this in flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, geometry, shapes

I am trying to have a circle shape like this in my flutter project. I tried using border-radius in a container. But it didn't work as I expected.

So, how can I have a shape like this given picture?

[image]

I tried using a container like this.

```
    Container(
            height: 72,
            width: 211,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30))
            ),
          )
```

Comment: Have you tried something to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I tried border-radius in a container. But it didn't work as I expected

Comment: post your code too?

Comment: can you share more elaborated image so that user can easily recognize the shape of the view that you want?

Comment: it's updated. please check @farhana

Comment: @anmol.majhail Please check the image

Comment: I have seen a few example pictures like this shape in some flutter project. So this is possible. But just got stuck in making them :)

Comment: You can always use [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) to achieve things like that. With CustomPaint you can draw arbitrary shapes on the screen wherever you want.

Comment: thanks. Let me try it out :D @MartinNiederl

Comment: @Rahi you can use arc image and place text where you want by using stack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can draw almost anything using CustomPaint, take a look:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html

In the code below, I draw something like that circle:

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(title: "", home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: CirclePainter(),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Paint lightBluePaint = Paint()..color = Color(0xFFbde5fa);
  final Paint bluePaint = Paint()..color = Color(0xFF5abef2);
  final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  );

  final TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white.withAlpha(240),
      fontSize: 18,
      letterSpacing: 1.2,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var rect = Rect.fromLTRB(
        -100, size.height - 120, size.width * 0.7, size.height + 250);

    final Path circle = Path()..addOval(rect);
    final Path smallCircle = Path()..addOval(rect.inflate(50));

    canvas.drawPath(smallCircle, lightBluePaint);
    canvas.drawPath(circle, bluePaint);

    drawText(canvas, size, 'Write now');
  }

  void drawText(Canvas canvas, Size size, String text) {
    textPainter.text = TextSpan(style: textStyle, text: text);
    textPainter.layout();
    textPainter.paint(canvas, Offset(50, size.height - 60));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

to implement your image preview you need to use [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) Class with [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) elements. I made a widget as your picture shown. circles in corners can be made with container with border-radius.

```
  Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: 250,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
        BoxShadow(
          color: Color(0x40000000),
          blurRadius: 5.0,
          spreadRadius: 0.0,
          offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Step 3',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              Text(
                'It is a long established fact that a reader will be '
                  'distracted by the readable content of a page when '
                  'looking at its layout.',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 150,
          right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 200,
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFB5E1F9),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(200),
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFF4FB6F0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(150),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 30,
          left: 30,
          child: Text(
            'Write now',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```